# Performance issues with complex nested RoR reservation system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm designing a Ruby on Rails reservation system for our small tour agency. It needs to accommodate a number of things, and the table structure is becoming quite complex.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before? What sort of issues might I come up against? And are performance/ validation likely to become issues?

In simple terms, I have a customer table, and a reservations table. When a customer contacts us with an enquiry, a reservation is set up, and related information added (e.g., paid/ invoiced, transport required, hotel required, etc).

So far so good, but this is where is gets complex. Under each reservation, a customer can book different packages (e.g. day trip, long tour, training course). These are sufficiently different, require specific information, and are limited in number, such that I feel they should each have a different model.

Also, a customer may have several people in his party. This would result in links between the customer table and the reservation table, as well as between the customer table and the package tables.

So, if customer A were to make a booking for a long trip for customers A,B and C, and a training course for customer B, it would look something like this.

```
CUSTOMERS TABLE
CustomerA
CustomerB
CustomerC
CustomerD
CustomerE
etc

RESERVATIONS TABLE
1. CustomerA

LONG TRIP BOOKINGS
CustomerA - Reservation_ID 1
CustomerB - Reservation_ID 1
CustomerC - Reservation_ID 1

TRAINING COURSE BOOKINGS
CustomerB - Reservation_ID 1
```

This is a very simplified example, and omits some detail. For example, there would be a model containing details of training courses, a model containing details of long trips, a model containing long trip schedules, etc. But this detail shouldn't affect my question.

What I'd like to know is:

1) are there any issues I should be aware of in linking the customer table to the reservations model, as well as to bookings models nested under reservations.

2) is this the best approach if I need to handle information about the reservation itself (including invoicing), as well as about the specific package bookings.

On the one hand this approach seems to be complex, but on the other, simplifying everything into a single package model does not appear to provide enough flexibility.

Please let me know if I haven't explained this issue very clearly, I'm happy to provide more information. Grateful for any ideas, suggestions or comments that would help me think through this rather complex database design.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you implement this as you describe above, the most challenging portion of this is going to be the composite key that you'll need to set up in order to tie a booking to a customer and a reservation, which is not natively supported by rails.  That being said, there is a composite key gem that can resolve this problem: http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/.  From a performance perspective, nothing you describe is raising red flags.

Comment: hi @MarcTalbot, thanks for your suggestions. I had intended to use a join table to handle this customer-reservation-bookings relationship. Probably polymorphic to accommodate the different booking types. I don;t know much about composite keys, and I'd be interested in your thoughts as to the relative merits of these two approaches. Thanks

Comment: A join table with an associated model can be useful for storing additional attributes for the association.  Eg: a calculated price per booking per customer.

Comment: I think you'd be better off taking a composite key approach, in the sense that this will eliminate a join that would end up being reflected all through your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built a large reservation system for travel operators and wholesalers, and I can tell you that it isn't easy. There seems to be similarity yet still large differences in the kinds of product booked.  Also, date-sensitivity is a large difference from other systems.

1) In respect to 'customers' I have typically used different models for representing different concepts.  You really have:

- a. Person / Company paying for the booking
- b. Contact person for emergencies
- c. People travelling

a & b seem like the same, but if you have an agent booking, then you might want to separate them.

I typically use a => 'customer' table, then some simple contact-fields for b, and finally for c use a 'passengers' table.  These could be setup as different associations to the same model, but I think they are different enough, and I tend to separate them - perhaps use a common address/contact model.

2) I think this is fine, but depends on your needs.  If you are building up itineraries for a traveller, then it makes sense to setup 'passengers' on the 'reservation', then for individual itinerary items, with links to which passenger is travelling on/using that item.

This is more complicated, and you must be careful to track dependencies, but the alternative is to not track passenger names, and simply assign quantities to each item (1xAdult, 2xChildren).  This later method is great for small bookings, so it seems to depend on if your bookings are simple, or typically built up of longer itineraries.

other)  In addition, in respect to different models for different product types, this can work well.  However, there tends to be a lot of cross over, so some kind of common 'resource' model might be better -- or some other means of capturing common behaviour.

If I haven't answered your questions, please do ask more specific database design questions, or I can add more detail about specific examples of what I've found works well.

Good luck with the design!

Comment: thanks @adzdavies, some useful pointers. I have pondered this issue about customers at length. From a design perspective, it would be much simpler to handle these as separate models. However, it would also be extremely useful to have a central contact list. I'm still debating over the product types. I'm wondering of single table inheritance would allow me to cover the commonalities, while still allowing me to accommodate the differences. I'm not too familiar with STI, so will need to research this.

Comment: one more, what do you mean by 'date sensitivity'?

Comment: Just the need to track dates per booking.  The inventory is not simply a number in stock, but how many spaces on a given date.

Comment: Also think of what happens if a product / inventory config changes, and you have existing bookings that have both travelled in the past and yet to travel (future).